# Why must I use try catch when I use global exception handling?

Tags: java, android, try-catch, uncaught-exception

I'm beginner in Java and Android. My problem is when I use setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in my code, some functions still need a try/catch block surrounding it, but I want throw all my exceptions to UncaughtException thread.

```
    public class MyAlarmReciever  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(context));

        try
        {   
            String imageURL = MyWebService.readFeed();
            DownloadAndSet.downloadFile(imageURL);  
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {           
            throw new RuntimeException(e);          
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java distinguishes checked and unchecked exceptions. Checked Exceptions **have to** be caught, no matter what.

**Correction**: Or you have to add the `throws` clause to the method. This postpones the urge to catch that exception to the caller of your method.

If you want them to be handled in the UncaughtExceptionHandler, you can "forward" them:

```
try{ 
   // blah "throws some checked exception type"
} catch ( Throwable e ) {
    // throw e; <- This will not work :( unless you add the "throws" clause.
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Unfortunately, just throwing the same Exception won't work, because you'd have to add the throws clause, which you do not want. You'll have to wrap it in a RuntimeException.

Comment: You can either catch an exception or throw it. "Have to be caught" is wrong here.

Comment: @JunedAhsan to rethrow them, you have to catch them first.

Comment: not really, you don't have to catch and re throw. Adding throws to method will simply do it.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I see your point, but adding throws will just move the need to add try/catch one stage further. OP wants them to fall through to UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: Besides, I personally, I think he shouldn't be doing this at all.

Comment: Regardless, you're technically incorrect so you should correct it.

Comment: I see, I'll add that.

Comment: If you simply re-throw the exception then why do u want to increase the lines of code ?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I don't think that my example code and adding the throws clause have the same effect. Or is my Java that rusty?

Comment: i use eclipse to create android app and i get this error: TheCheckedExceptionType cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @PatternProgrammer That was just an example, sorry. "TheCheckedExceptionType" does not really exist. You could just put "Exception" or even "Throwable" in there. And again: I do not consider this a good idea. Mostly, checked exceptions are checked ones for a good reason.

Comment: @tieTYT see my correction. I hope it is technically ok, now.

Comment: @Fildor in that case eclipse tell me surround throw e; with try and catch :(

Comment: @PatternProgrammer Can you add some example of that to your question?

Answer (score 1):

All checked exceptions in your code must be caught.

Further reading on checked vs unchecked exceptions:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method that throws an exception, requires you to either handle the exception using `try/catch` or `throw` the same exception.

As you don't want to handle the exception in your code and want all exceptions to be handled by your Default Exception handler so you need to add `throws` to all your methods where you don't want to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) says:

> Set the default handler invoked when a thread abruptly terminates **due to an uncaught exception**, and no other handler has been defined for that thread.

It doesn't relate to exceptions you *have to* catch.  An example of an exception you have to catch/throw is IOException.  An example of an exception you don't is NullPointerException.

So if your code causes a NullPointerException, the default handler will deal with it.  If your code (potentially) causes an IOException, you have to deal with it then and there (either by catching or throwing).

Answer (score 0):

What I have always done in my programs is create a exception handler method and call it every time I make a `try/catch` block. Many times I have had `Thread.sleep()` methods and I just send the exception to a common place to do "global" handling. In your global exception handler, you can also refer to this method.

Keep in mind that you might not always want to use this method because things like file streams might throw errors if a file already exists and you would want to take a different approach such as naming it something else than just stopping the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            catchException(e);
        }
    });
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);// Just an example of a possible exception thrower
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        catchException(e);
    }
}

public static void catchException(Throwable e) {
    // Deal with the exception here
    System.out.println("Oh no! You broke the program!!!");
    System.out.println("Here is the error btw: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

If you are using Eclipse, you can set the default automatic code generation for `try/catch` blocks to automatically include this method:
[image: Eclipse Catch Block Body]
You can also set project specific settings if you don't want this behaviour for all of your projects.